# Set image from SDWebImage to background of button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sdwebimage

I use SDWebImage in my project but I was wondering if there is a way to set the image to the background of a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                  options:0
                 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                     // progression tracking code
                 }
                 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                     if (image) {
                         // do something with image
                        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];


                     }
                 }];
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to import this class of `SDWebImage`

```
#import "SDWebImage/UIButton+webCache.h"
```

and `UIButton+webCache` this class is Category class so you can set your button background image like this,

```
[yourBTN sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"urlString.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: @reza_khalafi read the question and https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIButton%2BWebCache.h check this link

Comment: @UgoMarinelli :D :D

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3**

Been stuck for hours . **Mayank Patel's** answer is correct.

```
button.sd_setBackgroundImage(with: URL(string:url), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are method for this in SDWebImage

Import `#import <SDWebImage/UIButton+WebCache.h>`

Use any of this method:

```
- (void)sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state;
- (void)sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder;
- (void)sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options;
- (void)sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state completed:(SDWebImageCompletedBlock)completedBlock;
- (void)sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder completed:(SDWebImageCompletedBlock)completedBlock;
- (void)sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options completed:(SDWebImageCompletedBlock)completedBlock;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is working for me

```
cell.bProfileImage.sd_setBackgroundImage(with: URL(string:
individualChatsListArray[indexPath.row].profile_image), for:
UIControl.State.normal, placeholderImage: UIImage(named:
"default_profile"), options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0)) { (image,
error, cache, url) in

}
```